# For loop to populate a PDF with FPDF

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have generated a report in python that looks similar to the one below that I've taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmN2_R4KEg8) tutorial.

[image: Generate Page]

While this page is easy to set up if you manually enter the path to each image, like this:

```
     pdf.add_page()
     pdf.image("/Users/Foo/Graph1.png", 5, 20, WIDTH/2-10)
     pdf.image("/Users/Foo/Graph2.png", WIDTH/2, 20, WIDTH/2-10)
     pdf.image("/Users/Foo/Graph3.png", 5, 110, WIDTH/2-10)
     pdf.image("/Users/Foo/Graph4.png", WIDTH/2, 110, WIDTH/2-10)
     pdf.image("/Users/Foo/Graph5.png", 5, 200, WIDTH/2-10)
     pdf.image("/Users/Foo/Graph6.png", WIDTH/2, 200, WIDTH/2-10)
```

The above code will not work if the directory does not always have the same number of png files in it.

I started writing the function as below, but need help with the part that comes after it.

```
def addtopage(function):
   for f in os.listdir('path'):
      if f.endswith('png') in f:
         #add it to the next position in the pdf
```

My question is, how can I create a for loop that will automatically loop through the folder, grab every .png in the folder, and place them into the next position on a pdf page with the format in the image above?

Thank you!

Comment: So you have defined a procedure to do what you want, does it work?  If not what is wrong with it?  Stating "I have some theories on how I can accomplish this, but after messing around with it for some time I figured it's best if I ask for help here." isn't a question!

Comment: Seems that the image sizes are pretty static - you can simply add a counter for the number of files and perform the pdf.image() based on what the counter says

Comment: @itprorh66 My apologies, I've updated the post to be clearer.

Comment: @veedata Thanks for the reply, could you show me an example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```py
def addtopage(function):
   png_count = 0
   start_y = 20
   img_ht = 90
   for f in os.listdir('path'):
      if f.endswith('png') in f:
         if png_count%2 == 0
             pdf.image(f, 5, start_y, WIDTH/2-10)
         else:
             pdf.image(f, WIDTH/2-10, start_y, WIDTH/2-10)
             start_y += img_ht
         png_count += 1
         if png_count%6 == 0:
             pdf.add_page()
```

You could still improve this code and have some more variables that will allow for more flexibility, but this should give a good boilerplate for the same. Also, if you are using ppyfpdf, I would suggest taking a look at [fpdf2](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/index.html). It is a fork from PyFPDF itself and is being actively maintained ([PyFPDF](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf) received its last commit in 2018).

Answer (score 0):

I have five images in a file and I'd like to put two per page... the first two on one page, then the next two on the second and the last one on a third page.
in the end I want a loop, where each image is positioned one after the other, passing a page as soon as there's no more space for the next image... I think it should be easy but I can't do it.

[first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNOIj.jpg)
[second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN7qg.jpg)

I've copied the previous code, thank you very much.

```
png_count = 0
start_y = 50
img_ht = 115
for name in imagelist:
    if png_count%2 == 0:
        pdf.image(name, 20, start_y, 160, 100.4)
    else:
        start_y += img_ht
        pdf.image(name, 20, start_y, 160, 100.4)
    png_count += 1
    if png_count%3 == 0:
        pdf.add_page()
```

There are the first two figures on the first page, but then when I turn to the second page, the third figure goes to the bottom. I don't know why...

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution! Unfortunately it seems like you are asking for help and would be better suited to putting this in a new question, rather than as an answer to a different question.